# How to uniquely label a connected graph?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Given a connected graph $G$ with $V$ vertices and $E$ edges.

I want to assign an ID to each vertex in a way such that the ID combination of each pair of adjacent vertices is unique in the graph.

I was wondering:

1) how many IDs are need of a graph of $V$ vertices? is there any closed-form solution?

2) What if the graph is a planar graph?

Comment: Are you asking for a function that, given 2 isomorphic graphs, outputs the same labelling for both? What do you mean by 'how many labels'?

Comment: Hello @yuri, I mean, given a graph of V vertices, how many IDs do I need if I want to ensure the ID combination of each adjacent vertices is unique in the graph. I have added a more clear description of this problem. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe later I’ll be able to go more deeply, but I’ll start from trivial observations. Denote the minimum number of ID’s (which I shall call colors, as it is usual in graph theory) which allows to label the vertices of the graph $G$ satisfying the condition by $r=r(G)$. Then the number of different pairs of colors $r+{r \choose 2}$ is at least $E$. On the other hand, clearly $r\le V$.

I guess that the number $r(G)$ is very dependent on the structure of the graph $G$ and there may be no closed-form solution in the general case.

On the other hand, we can consider some simple graphs.

Let $G$ be a complete graph $K_V$ with $V\ge 3$. It is easy to check that $r(G)=V$. This implies $r(G)\ge\omega(G)$ for each graph $G$, where $\omega(G)$ is the size of the maximum clique in $G$.

Let $G$ be a complete bipartite graph $K_{p,q}$. Then all vertices in each part of the bipartition should have distinct colors, which implies $r(K_{p,q})\ge\max\{p,q\}$. On the other hand, this condition also assures the required coloring, implying that the inequality is, in fact, the equality.

Comment: Hi, Alex, Thanks for your reply. If we assume the graph is a connected planar graph and the max degree of the vertex is K. will these assumptions make this problem easier to analyze?

Comment: @ice_lin I'll try to apply these assumptions.

Comment: Another trivial lower bound is that $r$ is at least the maximum degree of any vertex in the graph. This implies your lower bound for $K_{p,q}$.